# OpenSource Mobile Terminal returns a Shell Script Invocation Error

Tags: ios, shell, terminal

After compiling the codes, XCode returns me an Shell Script Invocation Error saying that it cant exec './build_svnversion.sh' (Permission Denied).

The error returns a non editable script showing the error as follows.

ExternalBuildToolExecution svnversion

```
cd /Users/ClarenceLeong/Desktop/MobileTerminal
setenv ACTION 
setenv ALTERNATE_GROUP staff
setenv ALTERNATE_MODE u+w,go-w,a+rX
setenv ALTERNATE_OWNER ClarenceLeong
setenv ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS YES
setenv APPLE_INTERNAL_DEVELOPER_DIR /AppleInternal/Developer
setenv APPLE_INTERNAL_DIR /AppleInternal
setenv APPLE_INTERNAL_DOCUMENTATION_DIR /AppleInternal/Documentation
setenv APPLE_INTERNAL_LIBRARY_DIR /AppleInternal/Library
setenv APPLE_INTERNAL_TOOLS /AppleInternal/Developer/Tools
setenv APPLY_RULES_IN_COPY_FILES NO
setenv ARCHS i386
setenv AVAILABLE_PLATFORMS "iphonesimulator macosx iphoneos"
setenv BUILD_COMPONENTS "headers build"
setenv BUILD_DIR /Users/ClarenceLeong/Desktop/MobileTerminal/build
setenv BUILD_ROOT /Users/ClarenceLeong/Desktop/MobileTerminal/build
setenv BUILD_STYLE Debug
setenv BUILD_VARIANTS normal
setenv BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR /Users/ClarenceLeong/Desktop/MobileTerminal/build/Debug-iphonesimulator
setenv CACHE_ROOT /var/folders/uJ/uJpkvjMQFCSvMbSST47qrU+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501
setenv CLASS_FILE_DIR /Users/ClarenceLeong/Desktop/MobileTerminal/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/svnversion.build/JavaClasses
setenv CLONE_HEADERS NO
setenv COMBINE_HIDPI_IMAGES NO
setenv CONFIGURATION Debug
setenv CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR /Users/ClarenceLeong/Desktop/MobileTerminal/build/Debug-iphonesimulator
setenv CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR /Users/ClarenceLeong/Desktop/MobileTerminal/build/Debug-iphonesimulator
setenv COPYING_PRESERVES_HFS_DATA NO
setenv COPY_PHASE_STRIP NO
setenv DEAD_CODE_STRIPPING NO
setenv DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS YES
setenv DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT dwarf-with-dsym
setenv DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION NO
setenv DEPLOYMENT_POSTPROCESSING NO
setenv DERIVED_FILES_DIR 
setenv DERIVED_FILE_DIR /Users/ClarenceLeong/Desktop/MobileTerminal/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/svnversion.build/DerivedSources
setenv DERIVED_SOURCES_DIR /Users/ClarenceLeong/Desktop/MobileTerminal/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/svnversion.build/DerivedSources
setenv DEVELOPER_APPLICATIONS_DIR /Developer/Applications
setenv DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR /Developer/usr/bin
setenv DEVELOPER_DIR /Developer
setenv DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR /Developer/Library/Frameworks
setenv DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR_QUOTED "\"/Developer/Library/Frameworks\""
setenv DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR /Developer/Library
setenv DEVELOPER_SDK_DIR /Developer/SDKs
setenv DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DIR /Developer/Tools
setenv DEVELOPER_USR_DIR /Developer/usr
setenv DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE English
setenv DO_HEADER_SCANNING_IN_JAM NO
setenv DSTROOT /tmp/MobileTerminal.dst
setenv DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME .dSYM
setenv DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH /Users/ClarenceLeong/Desktop/MobileTerminal/build/Debug-iphonesimulator
setenv ENABLE_HEADER_DEPENDENCIES YES
setenv ENABLE_OPENMP_SUPPORT NO
setenv EXCLUDED_INSTALLSRC_SUBDIRECTORY_PATTERNS ".svn CVS"
setenv EXCLUDED_RECURSIVE_SEARCH_PATH_SUBDIRECTORIES "*.nib *.lproj *.framework *.gch *.xcode* (*) CVS .svn .git"
setenv FILE_LIST /Users/ClarenceLeong/Desktop/MobileTerminal/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/svnversion.build/Objects/LinkFileList
setenv FRAMEWORK_VERSION A
setenv GCC3_VERSION 3.3
setenv GCC_C_LANGUAGE_STANDARD c99
setenv GCC_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC NO
setenv GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL 0
setenv GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS YES
setenv GCC_VERSION 4.2
setenv GCC_WARN_ABOUT_DEPRECATED_FUNCTIONS NO
setenv GCC_WARN_ABOUT_RETURN_TYPE YES
setenv GCC_WARN_UNUSED_VARIABLE YES
setenv GENERATE_MASTER_OBJECT_FILE NO
setenv GENERATE_PKGINFO_FILE NO
setenv GID 20
setenv GROUP staff
setenv HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_FLAT_ENTRIES_FOR_TARGET_BEING_BUILT YES
setenv HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_FRAMEWORK_ENTRIES_FOR_ALL_PRODUCT_TYPES YES
setenv HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_NONPUBLIC_NONPRIVATE_HEADERS YES
setenv HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_PROJECT_HEADERS YES
setenv HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS /Users/ClarenceLeong/Desktop/MobileTerminal
setenv INFOPLIST_EXPAND_BUILD_SETTINGS YES
setenv INFOPLIST_OUTPUT_FORMAT binary
setenv INFOPLIST_PREPROCESS NO
setenv INSTALL_DIR /tmp/MobileTerminal.dst
setenv INSTALL_GROUP staff
setenv INSTALL_MODE_FLAG u+w,go-w,a+rX
setenv INSTALL_OWNER ClarenceLeong
setenv INSTALL_ROOT /tmp/MobileTerminal.dst
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.3
setenv JAVA_APP_STUB /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Resources/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
setenv JAVA_ARCHIVE_CLASSES YES
setenv JAVA_ARCHIVE_TYPE JAR
setenv JAVA_COMPILER /usr/bin/javac
setenv JAVA_FRAMEWORK_RESOURCES_DIRS Resources
setenv JAVA_JAR_FLAGS cv
setenv JAVA_SOURCE_SUBDIR .
setenv JAVA_USE_DEPENDENCIES YES
setenv JAVA_ZIP_FLAGS -urg
setenv KEEP_PRIVATE_EXTERNS NO
setenv LD_GENERATE_MAP_FILE NO
setenv LD_MAP_FILE_PATH /Users/ClarenceLeong/Desktop/MobileTerminal/build/svnversion-LinkMap--.txt
setenv LD_OPENMP_FLAGS -fopenmp
setenv LEGACY_DEVELOPER_DIR /Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer
setenv LINKER_DISPLAYS_MANGLED_NAMES NO
setenv LINK_WITH_STANDARD_LIBRARIES YES
setenv LOCAL_ADMIN_APPS_DIR /Applications/Utilities
setenv LOCAL_APPS_DIR /Applications
setenv LOCAL_DEVELOPER_DIR /Library/Developer
setenv LOCAL_LIBRARY_DIR /Library
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv MAC_OS_X_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION 10K540
setenv MAC_OS_X_VERSION_ACTUAL 1068
setenv MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAJOR 1060
setenv MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MINOR 0608
setenv OBJECT_FILE_DIR /Users/ClarenceLeong/Desktop/MobileTerminal/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/svnversion.build/Objects
setenv OBJROOT /Users/ClarenceLeong/Desktop/MobileTerminal/build
setenv ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH NO
setenv OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL 0
setenv OS MACOS
setenv OTHER_LDFLAGS -all_load
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
setenv PATH_PREFIXES_EXCLUDED_FROM_HEADER_DEPENDENCIES "/usr/include /usr/local/include /System/Library/Frameworks /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks /Developer/Headers /Developer/SDKs /Developer/Platforms"
setenv PLATFORM_NAME iphonesimulator
setenv PLIST_FILE_OUTPUT_FORMAT same-as-input
setenv PREBINDING NO
setenv PRECOMPS_INCLUDE_HEADERS_FROM_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR YES
setenv PRECOMP_DESTINATION_DIR /Users/ClarenceLeong/Desktop/MobileTerminal/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/svnversion.build/PrefixHeaders
setenv PRESERVE_DEAD_CODE_INITS_AND_TERMS NO
setenv PRODUCT_NAME svnversion
setenv PROFILING_CODE NO
setenv PROJECT MobileTerminal
setenv PROJECT_DERIVED_FILE_DIR /Users/ClarenceLeong/Desktop/MobileTerminal/build/MobileTerminal.build/DerivedSources
setenv PROJECT_DIR /Users/ClarenceLeong/Desktop/MobileTerminal
setenv PROJECT_FILE_PATH /Users/ClarenceLeong/Desktop/MobileTerminal/MobileTerminal.xcodeproj
setenv PROJECT_NAME MobileTerminal
setenv PROJECT_TEMP_DIR /Users/ClarenceLeong/Desktop/MobileTerminal/build/MobileTerminal.build
setenv REMOVE_CVS_FROM_RESOURCES YES
setenv REMOVE_GIT_FROM_RESOURCES YES
setenv REMOVE_SVN_FROM_RESOURCES YES
setenv RUN_CLANG_STATIC_ANALYZER YES
setenv SCAN_ALL_SOURCE_FILES_FOR_INCLUDES NO
setenv SDKROOT /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk
setenv SEPARATE_STRIP NO
setenv SEPARATE_SYMBOL_EDIT NO
setenv SHARED_DERIVED_FILE_DIR /Users/ClarenceLeong/Desktop/MobileTerminal/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DerivedSources
setenv SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR /var/folders/uJ/uJpkvjMQFCSvMbSST47qrU+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders
setenv SKIP_INSTALL NO
setenv SOURCE_ROOT /Users/ClarenceLeong/Desktop/MobileTerminal
setenv SRCROOT /Users/ClarenceLeong/Desktop/MobileTerminal
setenv STANDARD_C_PLUS_PLUS_LIBRARY_TYPE dynamic
setenv STRINGS_FILE_OUTPUT_ENCODING binary
setenv STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT YES
setenv STRIP_STYLE all
setenv SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS "iphonesimulator iphoneos"
setenv SYMROOT /Users/ClarenceLeong/Desktop/MobileTerminal/build
setenv SYSTEM_ADMIN_APPS_DIR /Applications/Utilities
setenv SYSTEM_APPS_DIR /Applications
setenv SYSTEM_CORE_SERVICES_DIR /System/Library/CoreServices
setenv SYSTEM_DEMOS_DIR /Applications/Extras
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_APPS_DIR /Developer/Applications
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR /Developer/usr/bin
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DEMOS_DIR "/Developer/Applications/Utilities/Built Examples"
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DIR /Developer
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DOC_DIR "/Developer/ADC Reference Library"
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_GRAPHICS_TOOLS_DIR "/Developer/Applications/Graphics Tools"
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_JAVA_TOOLS_DIR "/Developer/Applications/Java Tools"
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_PERFORMANCE_TOOLS_DIR "/Developer/Applications/Performance Tools"
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_RELEASENOTES_DIR "/Developer/ADC Reference Library/releasenotes"
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS /Developer/Tools
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DOC_DIR "/Developer/ADC Reference Library/documentation/DeveloperTools"
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS_RELEASENOTES_DIR "/Developer/ADC Reference Library/releasenotes/DeveloperTools"
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_USR_DIR /Developer/usr
setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_UTILITIES_DIR /Developer/Applications/Utilities
setenv SYSTEM_DOCUMENTATION_DIR /Library/Documentation
setenv SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DIR /System/Library
setenv TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY 1,2
setenv TARGETNAME svnversion
setenv TARGET_BUILD_DIR /Users/ClarenceLeong/Desktop/MobileTerminal/build/Debug-iphonesimulator
setenv TARGET_NAME svnversion
setenv TARGET_TEMP_DIR /Users/ClarenceLeong/Desktop/MobileTerminal/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/svnversion.build
setenv TEMP_DIR /Users/ClarenceLeong/Desktop/MobileTerminal/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/svnversion.build
setenv TEMP_FILES_DIR 
setenv TEMP_FILE_DIR /Users/ClarenceLeong/Desktop/MobileTerminal/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/svnversion.build
setenv TEMP_ROOT /Users/ClarenceLeong/Desktop/MobileTerminal/build
setenv TEST_AFTER_BUILD NO
setenv UID 501
setenv USER ClarenceLeong
setenv USER_APPS_DIR /Users/ClarenceLeong/Applications
setenv USER_LIBRARY_DIR /Users/ClarenceLeong/Library
setenv WARNING_CFLAGS -Wall
setenv XCODE_APP_SUPPORT_DIR /Developer/Library/Xcode
setenv XCODE_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION 4A2002a
setenv XCODE_VERSION_ACTUAL 0402
setenv XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR 0400
setenv XCODE_VERSION_MINOR 0400
./build_svnversion.sh
```

`error: can't exec './build_svnversion.sh' (Permission denied)`

If anyone encountered this problem, please do respond. I have tried searching and correcting as what people says changing the build/ to ${SYMROOT}. This was not successful too.

Another question: Will there be anyways to telnet without terminal on the iphone with no jailbreaking.